# How do I get the Objective-C class of an ivar?

Tags: objective-c, c, objective-c-runtime

I have a bunch of simple `NSManagedObject`s I create in a unit test. They just have a single `name` attribute of type `NSString *`. I always give my `NSManagedObject` the same `entityName` and `Class` name.

I want to avoid having to write the following code 30 times to set up a unit test:

```
@interface FooTest : GHTestCase {
Foo *foo;
}
@end
@implementation FooTest

- (void) setUp {
  [super setUp];

  foo = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Foo"
                                      inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
  foo.name = @"foo";
}
@end
```

Since `foo` is an ivar, I would think I should be able to write a macro to grab the type of `foo` (`Foo`), and use to create my `Foo`:

```
#define InsertManagedObjectByVariable(variable) \
do { \
variable = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([typeof(variable) class])]; \
variable.name = (NSString *) CFSTR(#variable);
} while(0)
```

However, this causes the following warning in clang:

```
variable = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityName:NSStringFromClass([typeof(variable) class])];
                                                                               ^
                                                             Expected expression
```

I also thought I could try to determine the type using the objective-c runtime `IVar` from `Ivar class_getInstanceVariable(Class cls, const char* name)`, but the only `IVar` type information available from the type encoding from `ivar_getTypeEncoding` is `id`, which isn't enough.

Can someone think of a way to obtain the type information of an `IVar` either at compile time or runtime?

Comment: Haven't tested this beyond seeing whether it compiles but can't you drop the `typeof()` and go with `[variable class]`?

Comment: No, because `variable` is nil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haven't tried obtaining class information from an ivar, but I know that `@property` declarations do encode information about the class. For instance, this property declaration:

```
@property (copy) NSString *normalString;
```

results in this attribute string (retrieved using [property_getAttributes()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html)) at runtime:

```
T@"NSString",C,VnormalString
```

I've written [some open source parsing code](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTRuntimeExtensions.m#L461) for this information.

Once you have the class name, you can convert it into an actual Class object using [NSClassFromString()](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000055-BCIJDAJA), and message the result from there.

**Disclaimer:** This probably shouldn't be depended upon for production applications, as it is undocumented.

Comment: Awesome. I knew when I wrote this question that you would know the answer. :)

Comment: Very interesting stuff. The inclusion of the type as a string is not documented; do you happen to know when it was introduced?

Comment: @RobNapier Hmm, really no idea. It's been working in Clang/Objective-C 2.0 for as long as I've tried it. Probably not a good idea to depend on it for production code, but very valuable for a testing solution like this.

Comment: This is actually documented in the [runtime prog guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtPropertyIntrospection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008048-CH101-SW6). That doc's been unchanged since 2009.

Comment: @Cris That's true for most of the syntax, but I believe Rob Napier was referring specifically to the class information in the type (which is not mentioned or shown in an example).

Comment: Right, I see what you mean. It's not so much un- as vaguely-documented. The doc does explicitly state that T is followed by the `@encode` type, but the format isn't identical to what `@encode` produces, and the doc only has examples for `id` type.

Answer (score 5):

An `id` is an `id`. At runtime, all Objective-C objects have the same type (`objc_object`). This is tied up in the dynamic nature of ObjC. For example, an object can change classes at runtime, new classes can be created, and the class hierarchy can change. You can ask a specific instance what its type is (since this is stored in `objc_object`), but a pointer to an object is just a pointer to an object. Even less than that: it's really just a pointer to a C struct that happens to have extra memory allocated at the end (to hold subclass ivars).

Your macro seems interesting, but you'll probably need to pass the classname as the second parameter rather than autodetecting it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I tried to outline that in my question. I hope someone with mad C preprocessor skills will see this and figure out how to turn the typeof() into an expression.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i misunderstand what you are trying to achieve.
To get the class of an iVar, can't you use the *class* method of the iVar?

like:

```
NSString *aString = @"random string";
NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromClass([aString class]));
```

Comment: Won't work if the ivar's value is nil, as is the case in the question.