# Is there a way to get the parameter's class type from a Method struct?

Tags: objective-c, introspection, objective-c-runtime

There is a method like this.

```
- (void)method: (CustomClass)param;
```

`CustomClass` inherits from `NSObject`.

I have a variable `m` below, which is the `Method` struct for that method.
I invoked `method_getArgumentType()` to get the argument types like this:

```
char szArgType[100] = {0,};
Method m = ...;
...
method_getArgumentType(m, 2, szArgType, 100);
```

I printed `szArgType`. It printed `@`, but I want to print `CustomClass`.
Is there a good way to get the real object class type for a parameter from a `Method` at runtime?

Comment: see also: [How do I get the ObjC class of an ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11265503/how-do-i-get-the-objective-c-class-of-an-ivar/11266383#11266383)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to do this. The interface type (the class) is used only by the compiler, and it does not preserve that information when it encodes the method signature.

The only information you can get at runtime is what's described in the [Type Encodings chapter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtTypeEncodings.html) of the Runtime Guide, which is whether the parameter is an object as opposed to any of the various POD types. The encoding for *any* object will be the same no matter its class, the `@` that you see there. (Essentially, everything is an `id` after the compiler is done with its type checking.)

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me. I used struct instead of class so I could check struct name through method_getArgumentType method.