# How do I get the class name of nil property of an Objective-C Class

Tags: objective-c, reflection

In Objective-C, if a properties value is `nil` using `[obj.property class]` returns `nil`. Is there a way to get the class name of a nil property of an Objective-C class?

Here is a very simple example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSDictionary *dict;

@end

@implementation MyClass

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        MyClass *c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
        NSLog(@"class %@, %@", [c.dict class], [c.dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] ? @"YES" : @"NO");
    }
}
```

Output is `class (null), NO`

Comment: You bet there is: [How do I get the ObjC class of an ivar?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11265503)

Comment: @JoshCaswell Even if the value of said ivar is `nil`?

Comment: @MikeD That has nothing to do with the *value* of the property. Think about it for a moment.

Comment: @MikeD: Yes, see the answer there. The runtime has some metadata about a class's ivars. It doesn't rely on the object in the ivar.

Comment: Thanks, I had been searching "property", not "ivar". This gets me going in the right direction. The answer has a disclaimer not to use it in production code. Is this true?

Comment: Well, if it's not documented, it could potentially change at any moment. However, the type encodings are generated by the compiler; the runtime has to stay in sync. Changing the encodings would be a _big_ change and couldn't go unannounced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about checking the return type of the getter?

```
Method m = class_getInstanceMethod([MyClass class], @selector(somePropertyGetter));
char type[32];
method_getReturnType(m, type, sizeof(type));
printf("Property type: %s\n", type);
```

**Edit:** to get the actual class name, introspect the property itself (code taken from [this category](https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/blob/master/Extensions/NSObject%2BProperties.m#L216)):

```
objc_property_t p = class_getProperty([MyClass class], "property");
// If you have a selector:
objc_property_t p = class_getProperty([MyClass class], sel_getName(someSelector));
const char *typeStr = property_getTypeString(p);
```

Comment: This uses the method's type encoding string and will only give you `@` for object types, not the class name.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, right.

Comment: OP is specifically asking for the class name.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Found another solution on Google :P updated.

Comment: Where is `property_getTypeString` defined? I don't see it [objc runtime](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/Reference/reference.html])

Comment: `property_getTypeString()` isn't in Apple's runtime. Looks like it was created by Alan Quatermain: https://github.com/AlanQuatermain/aqtoolkit/blob/master/Extensions/NSObject%2BProperties.m#L216, and it calls through to `property_getAttributes()`, which _is_ a public function in the runtime library, and also happens to be the answer on the question I've proposed as a duplicate.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Yes, I have indeed copied the code from there. I'll include a link.