# Getting the class type for a nil object?

Tags: objective-c

If I have an object that is already allocated, then doing `object.class` returns a non-nil value. So far so good. But, if the object has not yet been allocated, then accessing `object.class` returns `nil`.

I want to allocate an object based on its type dynamically, so for example:

```
@property NSArray *myArray;
...

// myArray is nil so far

self.myArray = [_myArray.class new];
```

However, I can't do this because `_myArray.class` is returning nil. So how would I determine the class type of a nil instance?

**Update:**
It is in fact possible. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15588765/458960) below.

Comment: myArray **MUST** be an array, if you follow naming convention.

Comment: Why don't you initialize every thing with `id`.

Comment: I think you in stuck in between a project where you want to find arrays and dicts. I did similar kind with a proper naming conventions. And from the object it self I truncated the classname and allocated and inited. I hope this idea helps you.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya no this is more in reference to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587465/creating-a-macro-to-perform-default-init

Comment: I will check that. But i wonder how every one assumed that it is NSArray? what if you used a object called parrot? then what object they would have used, MyPet, Bird etc !!!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya ya this question has nothing to do with arrays. Just a general question, with arrays being an example.

Comment: That is why I dint posted as answer, but Celebrities get upvotes on any answers...this may be Harsh but already proved in [Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/upvoting-based-on-celebrity-too-many-upvotes-excessive-rep-slurping).

Comment: I guess everybody, including me, answered with NSArray because it is what is taken as example `@property NSArray *myArray;`. However, this is of course to be generalized to all nil objects, as explained below.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the class name of nil property of an Objective-C Class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232164/how-do-i-get-the-class-name-of-nil-property-of-an-objective-c-class)

Answer (score 4):

You cannot determine the class of a `nil` instance, because it does not have one: it can be, quite literally, of any type derived from the type of the variable. For example, `NSMutableArray` is perfectly compatible with `NSArray`:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new]; // OK
NSArray *myArray = [NSMutableArray new]; // Also OK
```

Since the run-time capabilities of different subclasses can vary a lot, it is always up to your program to decide what kind of objects it wants.

Comment: Well the compiler knows what type of class the object belongs to. So why can't I? For example, if I do self.myArray = [NSNumber new], I'd get a warning, because the compiler knows what class myArray belongs to. Why can't I access this information?

Comment: @maq: What the compiler knows and what the running program knows are two separate things.

Comment: @maq The compiler knows enough to decide what's *not* to do, but it does not know enough to decide a single course of action ("single" is very important here). For example, if you try assigning `NSArray` an instance of `NSNumber`, the compiler knows that it's wrong. However, the compiler does not have enough knowledge to say that `NSArray` is "the" type of the object: it's one of many possible types, not "the" only possible type.

Answer (score 3):

Objective-C is a duck-typed language. This means that there are several things you can or can't do, and one of the things you can't is statically get a reference to the type of a variable.

Specifically, in your expression:

```
[_myArray.class new]
```

First, `_myArray.class` is evaluated, and then the result is sent the `new` message. Since `_myArray` is `nil` to begin with, `_myArray.class` returns `nil` as well, and the `new` message will return `nil` too, because sending any message to `nil` returns `nil` (or the closest representation to zero the return type has). This is why it doesn't work.

I suspect you come from a strongly-typed language like C#; what you're doing right now is the equivalent of `Foo foo = (Foo)Activator.CreateInstance(foo.GetType())`, which is sure to fail because `foo.GetType()` will either not compile or throw an exception (depending on if it's a class field or a local variable) since it was never assigned a value. In Objective-C, it compiles but it doesn't works. What you would want is `Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Foo))`, but notice that `Foo` is now hardcoded here too, so you might as well just create a `new Foo()`.

You say that the compiler "knows the type" of the object. This is not exactly true. First, `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are the root classes of the `NSArray` class cluster. This means that both are abstract, and `[NSArray alloc]` and `[NSMutableArray alloc]` return an instance of a subclass (`NSCFArray` last time I checked, and possibly something else; I recall seeing `_NSArrayM`). Maybe `[NSArray new]` works, but it's not giving you a plain `NSArray`.

Second, type safety is not enforced. Consider this code:

```
id foo = @"foo";
NSArray* bar = foo; // no warning!
```

So even though the compiler thinks that `bar` is an `NSArray`, it's in fact a `NSString`. If we plug in your code:

```
id foo = @"foo";
NSArray* bar = foo; // no warning!
NSArray* baz = [bar.class new];
```

`baz` is now an `NSString` as well. Since you ask for the runtime class of `bar`, the compiler has nothing to do with the operations.

And precisely because of that kind of behavior, you should probably instantiate your object with a class that *you* know, using `[NSArray new]` instead of trusting `_myArray` to be non-`nil`, and to be what you think it is.

Comment: +1 for a good explanation, though I'd disagree a little about Objective-C being duck-typed.  You can certainly treat it that way (asking if objects respond to a particular selector, which is appropriate in certain instances), but my experience has been that it's more common not to (instead asking if an object is a kind of a particular class).

Comment: To whoever downvoted my answer, I'd love to hear what you think is not right about it.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted, but check out the update to the question to see how this is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You must init the property , or it will be nil , send a message to a nil object , it will return nil , so ,you must first init the array like `_array = [[NSArray alloc] init];`

Answer (score 1):

So, for anyone wondering if this is possible, it is:

```
objc_property_t property = class_getProperty(self.class, "myArray");
const char * const attrString = property_getAttributes(property);
const char *typeString = attrString + 1;
const char *next = NSGetSizeAndAlignment(typeString, NULL, NULL);
const char *className = typeString + 2;
next = strchr(className, '"');
size_t classNameLength = next - className;
char trimmedName[classNameLength + 1];

strncpy(trimmedName, className, classNameLength);
trimmedName[classNameLength] = '\0';
Class objectClass = objc_getClass(trimmedName);

NSLog(@"%@", objectClass);
```

Output:

> NSArray

Done with the help of [extobjc](https://github.com/jspahrsummers/libextobjc/blob/master/extobjc/EXTRuntimeExtensions.m).

Comment: Well, you did not get a type from a `nil`: rather, you got a type from the class metadata of its enclosing object `self`, which is not the same thing. Besides, in this particular case it's perfectly useless: `NSArray` is immutable, so what you're going to get from a `new` is an array that is permanently empty.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with arrays. I just wanted to get the class type of a nil property, and this does it.

Comment: It does not get a class of a `nil` object: all it does is getting a class of a declared variable from your class, which happens to be `nil` at the time when you get the class.

Comment: You didn't get the type of `nil`, you got the type of the property itself.  Note that that code is grubbing around in internal implementation details that are likely to change over time.  Note, as well, that code using this kind of dynamic behavior is generally indicative of really bad design.  It also isn't clear what you are going to do with such dynamically allocated instances;  how will you initialize them?!?

Comment: @bbum this is mostly related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587465/creating-a-macro-to-perform-default-init

Answer (score -1):

### Nil has no class type

In Objective-C the actual class on an instance variable is only determined at runtime. So, you can't know the class of a nil object.

This is not an issue in your situation since you only need to do:

```
NSArray *myArray = [NSArray new];
```

Or

```
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] init];
```

### In Objective-C most decisions are deferred to the runtime

(as much as possible)

> Objective-C is a runtime oriented language, which means that when it's
> possible **it defers decisions about what will actually be executed** from
> compile & link time to when it's actually executing **on the runtime**.
>
> This gives you a lot of flexibility in that you can redirect messages
> to appropriate objects as you need to or you can even intentionally
> swap method implementations, etc.
>
> This requires the use of a runtime
> which can introspect objects to see what they do & don't respond to
> and dispatch methods appropriately. If we contrast this to a language
> like C. In C you start out with a main() method and then from there
> it's pretty much a top down design of following your logic and
> executing functions as you've written your code. A C struct can't
> forward requests to perform a function onto other targets.

*Source: [Understanding the Objective-C Runtime](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.fr/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html)*

Comment: Why the downvote? Isn't the answer appropriate? If you downvote, at least comment, so that I can improve the post.